# configuration manager constrings

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, configurationmanager

i am using the configuration manager to store my connection string. however, some unhandled exception occurs when i am trying to connect to my database.

here is my webconfig code

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Connection" connectionString="server=PC2-HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=project;uid=sa;pwd=Temp123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

code behind on my button

```
 string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
        con.Open();

        if (con.State>0) {
            Response.Write("asdasd");
        }
```

thanks in advance

edit: the exception im having is InvalidOperationException was unhandled by the user code. instance failure. no other details >.<

edit2: the exception points on con.Open();

Comment: btw, if i hard code that constring there, it would work just fine.

Comment: Please add the exception details buddy

Comment: do you get this error also on the first time you connect?

Comment: if i didn't use the configuration manager, and if hard coded my constring, it would connect to the database without any errors.

Comment: does you has add con.Close() statment  on last line ?

Comment: even if i have the con.Close(), it won't even reach that line xD

Comment: did you try debug the code to see you get the currect conn?

Comment: yes, i've tried to hard code my connection. and it connected

Comment: you didnt understand my question.. try to put a brakepoint and check the value you get in your string connString